# Крымская республиканская аварийно-спасательная служба «КРЫМ-СПАС». Стоит ли писать все заглавными в названии?

Tags: названия, буквы

Крымская республиканская аварийно-спасательная служба «КРЫМ-СПАС». Стоит ли писать все буквы заглавными в названии, а именно КРЫМ-СПАС?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Правильно*: **Крымская республиканская аварийно-спасательная служба «КРЫМ-СПАС»**.

*Комментарий*: я в таких случаях предпочитаю ориентироваться на оф. сайт и/или какие-нибудь оф. документы. Вот, к примеру, как написано в шапке некоего документа из раздела "документы" на оф сайте организации:

> Государственное казенное учреждение Республики Крым «Крымская
> республиканская аварийно-спасательная служба «КРЫМ-СПАС»

Comment: Это понятно. Но они себя как угодно могут назвать. А с точки зрения русского языка?

Comment: @flossyU а на основании каких правил вы хотели бы сделать все начальные буквы в названии заглавными?

Comment: Я бы не хотела как раз....хотя бы Крым....)

Comment: @flossyU См. комментарий Грамоты: new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=287457 // Замечу, что если вы используете название без родового "хвоста" и в обиходе, а не в документах, то, мне думается, следует ориентироваться уже не на оф. документ, а на Розенталя: "В выделяемых кавычками названиях предприятий, фирм и т. п. первое слово (и все имена собственные) пишется с прописной буквы..." Вероятно, будет верно писать так: «Мой знакомый работает в "Крым-спасе"».